# Total Curvature of 4 pi

Tags: surfaces, minimal-surfaces

What does it mean for a surface to have a total curvature of $4\pi $?

I have seen that both the catenoid and Enneper surface are the only minimal surfaces that have this total curvature, but I don't really understand what significance this has?

Could anyone please explain this?

Comment: I think your question is "what is a minimal surface"?

Comment: I know that for a surface to be minimal it has zero mean curvature, I get that. I just don't understand what significance that the total curvature being 4 pi has? Like what is it about the Enneper surface and catenoid that classifies them as having such a total curvature, geometrically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well first of all these have total curvature $-4\pi$, not $4\pi$.

The Gauss-Bonnet theorem tells us that the total curvature of a surface is equal to $2\pi$ times the Euler characteristic of the surface. Moreover we know that the Euler characteristic of a connected surface is always an integer that is at most 2.

So in general we might want to ask: What are all connected minimal surfaces without boundary in $\mathbb{R^3}$ of with total curvature $2\pi n$? We see this is the same as asking that the Euler characteristic be n.

Well, if $n=1,2$ the answer is none, since a minimal surface has nonpositive Gaussian curvature everywhere. Now we can go down from there trying to understand the most topologically simple minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

For $n=0$ it's not hard to figure out that a plane is the only connected minimal surface without boundary in $\mathbb{R^3}$ that has total curvature 0.

What you are saying is that these are the only two minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with Euler characteristic $-2$. So we see this case still has a relatively nice answer.

But as we decrease $n$ even further the story becomes increasingly complicated, and a general answer is unknown.

Comment: The Gauss-Bonnet theorem tells us that the total curvature of a surface is equal to 2π times the Euler characteristic of the surface is only for compact surfaces.

Comment: One can define a version of the Euler Characteristic which makes sense for surfaces with ends. More or less you just triangulate the surface except for the ends, do the usual $V-E+F$ thing and add in terms for the ends. With some reasonable restrictions on your triangulation what you get will be independent of the triangulation, hence deserving to be called the Euler characteristic. But yes you are right, you cannot immediately apply the "out of the box" Gauss-Bonnet theorem in this context.

Comment: The case for a non-compact manifold is different to compact manifold-with-boundary, for which there is a version of Gauss-Bonnet. Take for example the graph $z=x^2+y^2$, this clearly has positive total curvature whilst $z=x^2-y^2$ has negative total curvature, although these surfaces are topologically equivalent. (One thing that one does have in the non-compact case is the Cohn-Vossen inequality, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn-Vossen%27s_inequality). The Euler characteristic of a catenoid is the same as that for a cylinder, namely 0. Not -2.

Comment: Ah i think you are referring to a kind of alternative Euler characteristic that is different for the standard topological one.. maybe you could edit your answer to draw attention to this?

Comment: Yes, there are absolutely technical issues here which I totally swept under the rug. And yes, you have to use a slightly non-standard notion of Euler characteristic adapted for surfaces with ends. However I'd like to note that what the question actually asks to explain the significance of the result, not to give a detailed technical proof, so I think I'll stand by my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For calculate the finite total curvature of a complete minimal surface $\phi:M\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, by start from the topology of $\bar{M}$ and the geometry of ends.

An $\mathbf{end}$ of a completle minimal surface of finite total curvature is the image $c_i=\phi(D_i-p_i)$ of a sufficiently small punctured disk $D_i-p_i$ on $\bar{M}$ with centered at the point $p_i$.

$\mathbf{Theorem}$. If $g$ is the genus of $\bar{M}$, $M\cong{\bar{M}-\{p_1,...,p_r\}}$
and $d_1,...,d_r$ are the multiplicities of the ends $c_1,...,c_r$, and $\tau$ the total curvature

$$\tau(M)=2\pi(2-2g-r-\sum_{j=1}^rd_j)=2\pi(\chi(\bar{M})-r-\sum_{j=1}^rd_j).$$

--M=Catenoid has two ends. $r=2, d_1=d_2=1$, and $\bar{M}=\mathbb{S}^2$. Consequently

$$\tau(M)=2\pi(2-2-2)=-4\pi.$$

--The M=Enneper has one end of multiplicitiy $d_1$, and $\bar{M}=\mathbb{S}^2$, $\tau(M)=-4\pi$ Consequently $d_1=3$.

Comment: Do you have a reference? Thanks.

Comment: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81988304.pdf